# Simple.Odata.Client returns old data

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, simple.odata.client

I am using Simple.Odata.Client in my WCF service which invokes OData service. The issue is that i am getting old data with every request. I have to make IIS reset to get fresh data.
Following is my code which is using Simple.Odata.Client fluent Api.

```
 var x = ODataDynamic.Expression;
                    IEnumerable<Users> testdata = client
                        .For<Users>()
                        .Filter(x.Email.Contains("test"))                       
                        .FindEntriesAsync()
                        .Result;
```

Can somebody help me find out how to get updated data with every request?
Thanks.